# How do I create a wage calculator?

Tags: bash, time, calculator

I want to be able to print an amount that goes up every second by a specific amount until I stop the script. Ive been trying to print an update of how much I'm being paid by the second (or hour) live whilst I work, how would I go about doing that in bash?

Comment: Have you googled for bash calculator script or something like that?

Comment: You would probably use `bc` to divide the amount you are being paid on a longer scale.

Comment: I want to be able to print an amount that goes up every second by a specific amount until I stop the script. I havent found any way of doing that as of yet and not calculator scripts so far

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
total=0
increment=50
while :
do
  total=$((total + increment))
  printf '$%.2f\n' $(bc <<< "scale=2; $total / 100")
  sleep 1
done
```